# Google Apps Script getRange() Syntax

Tags: google-apps-script

My apps script code works when I use:

```
sheet.getRange("B2:D7").setValue(10);
```

But it does not work when I use:

```
sheet.getRange("DTstart:DTend").setValue(10);
```

Although,

```
var DTstart = B2;
var DTend = D7;
```

How do I circumvent this error? Is there a way to get the reference for a cell assigned to a variable? The value of DTstart and DTend changes throughout the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to put the value using `DTstart` and `DTend`.
- Values of `DTstart` and `DTend` are `B2` and `D7`, respectively.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When `B2` is used as a string, please modify to `"B2"`
- When `DTstart` and `DTend` are used as the variables, please modify to `DTstart + ":" + DTend` instead of `"DTstart:DTend"`.

#### Modified script:

```
var DTstart = "B2"; // Modified
var DTend = "D7"; // Modified
sheet.getRange(DTstart + ":" + DTend).setValue(10); // Modified
```

#### Note:

- In above case, `10` is put to the cells of `B2:D7`.

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.